# CMS for rolebased content-delivery

Tags: content-management-system

We are researching CMS systems to use for our next news-portal. 
Before people are voting this to be closed, please bear in mind that this question has been well researched and there is not a lot of info out there.

The requirements are that we need to **deliver role-based content**.
This means that we need to have different roles of users, e.g. guest, staff, recruiter, director etc..
And **based on the users role, we will serve different news-articles**. 
All news articles should be accessible to all roles, so the difference is only what news are highligheted on the frontpage.

There is a HUGE amount of different CMS systems out there, so if anyone could shed some light on which ones might serve my need I would be extremly happy. This kind of personalized content delivery seems to be either not well documented or not usally supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll presume your site is to have reasonably heavy traffic, you're looking for a robust system, and you can bring some PHP developer expertise to bear. (If your development team mostly knows Java, you should start examining systems like dotCMS and Alfresco - but I can't speak to their roles-based content and personalisation capabilities.)

If you need an industrial strength system and can go with PHP, Drupal should definitely be at the top of your shortlist. There are, however, a few PHP alternatives beyond Joomla and Wordpress - notably [MODX Revolution](http://modx.com/revolution/).

Drupal does very well with user roles. They are baked into the core of the product, and so Drupal is frequently used on membership-based sites and news portals. It runs the website for The Economist, for instance. Developers who know PHP should find their way around it pretty fast. Only rule it out if you are under a constraint such as needing to use Java or .net technology.

Joomla used to have just three user roles but their system has improved notably over the past couple of years and you can now create your own user groups.

Wordpress uses plugins for these sorts of tasks and can be made to do the job. It is a system well suited to quick starts, and its blogging interface is justly admired. But it wasn't originally designed with fine-grained user roles in mind, and using it on a job like this may be stretching its capabilities. Its architecture gets progressively harder to work with as you move away from core blogging tasks.

MODX has a very flexible and robust architecture for user roles and content access. MODX lets you serve up roles-based content very easily, and its sophisticated caching gives you a pretty good performance trade-off. It scales well too, although Drupal remains the king of scalability in this field. The bad news is that MODX's system of roles and permissions takes work to understand. The good news is that you only need to understand it once.

MODX has been very well architected so that you can build on top of it very quickly. That is not always true of Drupal, Joomla or WordPress. Drupal does benefit from a very long list of contributed "modules" to extend the system. But if you think you may need to do things which are not already built into the CMS or offered as an add-on - or if you are not enthusiastic about Drupal's steep learning curve - MODX Revolution may be your best bet.

I've [summarised elsewhere on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818684/what-are-the-questions-that-needs-to-asked-before-choosing-a-cms/) the things you need to think about more generally in choosing a CMS, but people are your most important consideration - the people who will use the system, the people who will build it, and the broader politics of your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The top three CMS' that I have personally dealt with are Wordpress, Drupal and Joomla. All three provide you with multiple role groups.

All three are simple to install, but nothing beats Wordspress' speedy install. I really liked that.

In terms of ease of use, in my opinion Wordpress is the easiest, then Joomla and lastly Drupal. However this can be biased based on the users experience with each system.

When it comes to creating templates, I really had fun creating templates for Wordpress, Drupal was alright, but I really dread creating templates with Joomla.

All three have an enormous base of available plugins, but I am the type that likes to create my own plugins and wordpress proved easiest for me to work with. I had difficulty comprehending the backend knowledge of Joomla(but I am only a newbie programmer) and I did not really do any plugin development with Drupal so I cant comment on that.

Thus, from my evaluation you might say Wordpress is the best option. However it is best for me as it works for me. You may have different preferences so I would advice give each a try but only dive into the ones you are truly interested in.

Lastly, if you cant find anything that suits your needs, this may be pretty obvious, but you could look into creating your own CMS.

Cheers and good luck in your quest to finding the perfect CMS for your needs!

Answer (score 0):

**I would suggest [Drupal](http://drupal.org/).**

It is a great CMS for handling multiple role groups. Its also uses something called `Views` which integrates very well with role groups allowing you the flexibility to show content based on the users groups.

The only issue I can see is the learning curve. Drupal can be a little confusing **at first** to understand.

The primary and strongest benefit is the rich and vibrant Drupal community and infrastructure that exists around the Drupal code base.

Hope that help :)

Answer (score 0):

The question as is is basically unanswerable. Nearly all CMS provide role-based content delivery, so that doesn't provide you with a differentiator. Describe the other requirements you have, both functional and non-functional (performance, #users, #articles, #images, #pageviews/day etc). Do you need to use it out of the box or do you want to do some development? How much? Can you upgrade modules to a new version yourself? What expertise does your team have?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Alfresco](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Download_and_Install_Alfresco).
It should fulfill all your requirements and it provides following facilities
Document Management
Web Content Management
Records Management
Image Management
Content Repository

You can condigure roles/permissions add/update/delete users/groups and lots of stuff